Windows Boot: Stuck in Boot loader
This question is about a Laptop which has Windows 10 64-Bit and 32-Bit in a dual boot configuration via Windows boot manager.
A CPU upgrade (change of the CPU, bought used) was recently performed. I did test if it was working fine and also could see the improved performance (increased clock speed and correct CPU-name shown in Task manager).
The problem occured some days later when the device should have been used for the first time after the upgrade. The vendor logo gets shown, then a screen flash happens and then after the dots spin for a short time they stop moving. So it does not reach the screen for the selection of the windows version.
I was able to boot to windows on a different device with the drive so the drive is not broken. Also Windows and the boot manager seem to be fine.
Using a live-system I was able to boot to Ubuntu and could see that it still had the correct amount of RAM (no modul failed completely), also it was possible to open the drive in the live-system (SATA access possible).
For me it looks like that every part is working (on it's own) but not together.
I also tried to use a USB-Stick to enter recovery mode but it gets stuck at the windows language selection screen (no keyboard and mouse usage possible).
The drive requires legacy boot.

It seems the new CPU is not compatible with the boot manager. My inclination would be to make the machine boot directly to 64-bit Windows 10, and run 32-bit Win 10 in a virtual machine, such as Oracle's free VirtualBox. This will also make your decision tree simpler, when, on Oct 14, 2025, MS no longer updates Windows 10. You can upgrade the main OS to Windows 11, if you PC is compliant, or to Linux, keeping the 32-bit Win 10 virtual machine unchanged.

As far as I am aware both in the current setup and your proposed variant it uses the Windows Boot Manager so I don't see how this could help. About the 32-bit Windows: Only the 64-bit variant is really needed so in principle your idea would be ok if it helps.
The situation is also kind of strange as it was working on the day that I installed the CPU and I also did serval reboots.
